# Use variable from function in one cpp file in another cpp file c++

Tags: c++, global-variables, extern

I'm sending a variable from a function from one cpp file to another using a header file and extern. The issue is that the files are not filled when they arrive to the second cpp file.

```
//Tmp.h 
//Declare tmp_user and tmp_pass
extern ustring tmp_user;
extern ustring tmp_pass;



//TmpOne.cpp
//define tmp_user and tmp_pass
#include "Tmp.h"

ustring tmp_user; //define outside of function
ustring tmp_pass;

function(blah, blah){    
    tmp_user = username; //fill the variable within the function
    tmp_pass = password;
//more code
}



//TmpTwo.cpp
//use the defined variables
#include "Tmp.h"

login(tmp_user, tmp_pass) //Both of the defined variables are empty.
{
    //some function
}
```

My issue is that both of the variables are empty when called in my second cpp file. I'm using visual studio 2010 and both of the cpp files are in the same project.

Comment: Are you actually calling `function(blah, blah)` to initialise the variables?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) how to ask questions, but, for starters, please put a minimum, compilable example and the full text of the error messages, so we can see what problems you are having....

Comment: Yeah fucntion(blah, blah) creates the two variables i need and then I just fill my global variables tmp_user and tmp_pass with these created variables. I'm not calling the function(blah, blah) in my tmpTwo.cpp file just the variables.

Comment: Hi @Massa The full code would be several pages long which is why I've shortened it to the issue I'm having. The error is that when the global variables tmp_user and tmp_pass are used in the TmpTwo.cpp file they are empty instead of being filled by the values from TmpOne.cpp. I hope that makes sense. I can post the full code but the rest of the code works fine its just this addition of global variables that I'm making that is the issue.

Comment: Notice I didn't ask for the full code. I just asked for a [minimum, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can evaluate. And the complete text of the error messages!

Comment: You've described what function(blah, blah) does, but you haven't told me if you actually *call* it somewhere. The execution of that function is what will initialise the two global variables. If you put a breakpoint on the line `tmp_user = username`, and on the line where you read `tmp_user` then you can see if the assignment correctly happens before the read.

Comment: What @Massa means, is that you should be able to reduce your code down to a simple amount that just shows your problem, but is still itself a complete, compilable program that other people could compile and run and see the same problem. You've cut out code unrelated to the issue which is helpful, but you've left us with snippets not a real program which makes it almost impossible for us to see what's going on.

Comment: Ah I understand what you guys are saying now, I'll try to figure out a way to make the code more presentable and complete and edit the existing code. As to your question @WillW yes the function is executed and works fine the tmp_user and tmp_pass files are filled in correctly within the TmpOne.cpp file and then after this is executed the next file TmpTwo.cpp is executed but within it the tmp_user and tmp_pass variables are empty.